# Getting mouse position doesn't work if button is clicked

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm trying to get mouse position(in-window) whenever the left mouse button is pressed using:

```
def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        print(event.pos())
```

however, any kind of interactive widget overrides it, for example- clicking a button doesn't print mouse position, same with line edit and others(maybe except label). How would I get the mouse position even if those widgets are clicked?

Comment: A `mousePressEvent` is only called by the widget that receives and accepts it. Since what you're citing are all widgets that actually *use* mouse button events, they obviously receive *their own* mouse event and that event is not relayed to any of their parents. Thats, both for logical reasons and obviously performance. But, I'm under the impression that you might have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to receive/intercept mouse events that are aimed for other widgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

In the case of QWidgets, you have to take into account:

- The transmission of the mouse event is from the top widget(child) to the bottom widget(parent).
- If an element consumes the mouse event (ie use `event.accept()`) then that event will no longer be transmitted.

### Solution:

If you want to detect the mouse event on a window then you could monitor that event on the window itself (QWindow) through an eventfilter:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, QEvent, QObject, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QLineEdit,
    QPushButton,
    QTextEdit,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
)


class MouseHelper(QObject):
    pressed = pyqtSignal(QPoint)
    released = pyqtSignal(QPoint)

    def __init__(self, window):
        super().__init__(window)
        self._window = window

        self.window.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def window(self):
        return self._window

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if self.window is obj:
            if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
                self.pressed.emit(event.pos())
            elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:
                self.released.emit(event.pos())
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


class Widget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        button = QPushButton("Press me")
        lineedit = QLineEdit()
        textedit = QTextEdit()

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(lineedit)
        lay.addWidget(textedit)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = Widget()
    w.show()

    helper = MouseHelper(w.windowHandle())
    helper.pressed.connect(lambda point: print("pressed:", point))
    helper.released.connect(lambda point: print("released:", point))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```